# How to compile & test "apps-for-android"?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, google-code

http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/

I have eclipse setup with Subversive plugin, I can download the codes down to my eclipse with the SVN method URL, but I just couldnt find a way to compile this code successfully!

Can any kind soul give this noob a step by step guide on how to get apps-for-android locally, compile, and run it on my test phone?

Edit:
Basically, in Eclipse with Subversive plugin, I create a new project by

File->New->Other->SVN->Project from SVN

then I use this URL, http://apps-for-android.googlecode.com/svn

Then on this screen, I dont know what I should select, so I chosed: Checkout as a project with the name specified

[image]

Then the codes got downloaded to my workspace, with the SVN metadatas.

In my Eclipse, I can see that a new project has been created, but its not an android project.

I tried to use Android Tools to convert it to an Android project, but of course it did not work.

I also try to simply create a new project with the downloaded codes, and I was never able to compile it because Eclipse says there is an error with the project, but I cannot find the error at all.

I thought this is supposed to be very simple, but I have spent one afternoon on this, so thus looking if anyone has done this before to advise me...

Thanks.

Comment: You need to describe what you have tried and what steps that are failing. Are there any specific issues to get apps-for-android starting that is not common to other applications you have created?

Comment: Ok, I will edit my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVN is simply a version control system for source code. Importing that code with SVN into Eclipse doesn't mean it will create Android projects for the sample code you're importing.

Once you've imported apps-for-android (by the way, you don't need the SVN plug-in at all, doing it from the command line works just as well), you can then compile the code by creating separate Android projects for each sample app.

In Eclipse, go to File->New->Android Project. Then click on Create Project from Existing Source source, and click on the button to find the sources of the program (the path has to go all the way to the App name (for example: /Users/amt/apps-for-android/apps-for-android-read-only/SpriteMethodTest).

The steps above assumes you already have the Android plug-in installed along with the Android's SDK with the platform version of your choice.

After creating your Android project, (depending on your Eclipse settings) it will compile it automatically or you can do it manually, right click on your project and select Run As Android Application. If the emulator is not running do this prior, else I think it should launch it for you.

Comment: Thank you, so at least now I know I *HAVE* to create a separate new project, in fact, I tried that, and I get a "Type R is already defined" error no matter what I do.. I know its a common error, and usually can be fixed by removing the R.java, or clean the project. but it doesnt work for me this time. I will make a different question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was scratching my head over this, too.  The process below seemed to work for me - YMMV.

*load the svn url in eclipse with the svn plugin (http://apps-for-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk for this case)

- Look up the package name of the sample app you want to load - for "Amazed" it is "com.example.amazed" - you'll be stuck in a modal dialog later and need it
- Check out the app using New Project Wizard ("Amazed" in this case), and choose "Android Project"
- Enter the project name - I used "Amazed" here as well, but don't think it matters
- Pick a target that works for the app (will depend on the app, of course) - 2.2 works for Amazed, but you can change it later
- Enter the application name (I used "Amazed" again)
- for "Package name", use the one you noted above (it might not matter, but then if you use something else it might confuse eclipse later or create some other crud you'll need to remove - let me know)
- click finish
- it should download and then build things, and then it will complain because R.java is under both "gen" and is in the source directory (in this case for this app)
- delete/move the R.java under src
- run it as an android application

Since this is a checkout of a read-only repository, you'll need to move it later if you want to do your own stuff on it and store in your own repository.  in that case, it might be better to just check it out somewhere else and then go through the import process.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Self Explanatory to Install Android SDK and Emulator.

Comment: i already have ADT, eclipse, and have made a few apps before without problem. Please read the details.